# How to Redirect a Child Popup Window to a Different URL as soon as its loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript/jQuery to redirecting a child popup window. I am using the following code to redirect it, but it is not working.

```
 $('#opennewwin').click(function(){
    var strURL =dynurlpath+"start.swe?SWECmd=ExecuteLogin&SWEAC=SWECmd=GotoView&SWEView=Home+Page+View+(WCC)&SWERF=1&SWEBU=1";
    var w = window.open(strURL, 'childwin', 'height=' + screen.height + ',width=' + screen.width + '');

    window.w.location.replace(dynurlpath+"start.swe?SWECmd=GotoView&SWEView=Home+Page+View+(WCC)&SWERF=1&SWEHo="+SWEHo+"&SWEBU=1&SRN="+MySRN1);
}
```

Here as soon as I enter credentials for login it takes me to a view which is set up as the startup view in the application, though I gave the url of Home Page. I can't change the start up view yet I need to go to the Home Page of the application. So, I thought of achieving the same after loading of the startup view and then redirecting the page to the Home Page.I tried it with this code but it is not working.

I think I am missing how to capture the location of child Popup and redirect it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

not much code but i have used javascript, hope it's what you're looking for

```
function openWin(win)
{
    var win = window.open(win);
    win.location.assign('http://google.co.uk');
}

openWin('url.php');
```

use window.location.assign and not window.replace